# Pop from GLib singly-linked list

Tags: c, list, glib

How does one idiomatically "pop" from the start of a [singly-linked list in GLib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html)? There are several functions that can be glued together but don't stand out as the intended inverse of [`g_slist_prepend`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html#g-slist-prepend).

Comment: Why not use a (de)queue if you want push/pop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your use case, either

```
// pop and discard head
list = g_slist_delete_link(list, list);
```

or

```
// pop head but keep it for further use
GSList *head = list;
list = g_slist_remove_link(list, head);
// do stuff with head
g_slist_free1(head);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [double-ended queue](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Double-ended-Queues.html), which has `g_queue_push_head` and `g_queue_pop_head`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = g_slist_remove(list, list->data);
```